# Database Error code 1146 - local vs. online

Tags: php, sql, database, localhost

I am new to this site - be gentle please :P
mySQL database on localhost works for an insert statement,but as soon as I change the database connection to the server connection it gives me the error: Error code 1146: 1146 without any error description. What could be the reason?
 According to my error capturing logic, the connection is successful all the way up to the part of the query run. On the local version it works like a charm. any ideas?

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
if($errors == 0)
        {
            $DBConnect = @mysql_connect("db.start.ca", "nokeekwe", "classifiedlol");
            if($DBConnect === FALSE)
            {
                echo "<p>Unable to connect. " .
                "Error code " . mysql_errno() . ": " .
                mysql_error() . "</p>\n";
                $errors++;
            }
            else
            {
                $DBName = "nokeekwe";
                $result = @mysql_select_db($DBName, $DBConnect);
                if($result === FALSE)
                {
                    echo "<p>Unable to select DB. " .
                    "Error code " . mysql_errno($DBConnect) .
                    ": " . mysql_error($DBConnect) .
                    "</p>\n";
                    $errors++;
                }
            }
        }

        if($errors > 0)
        {
            echo "<p>Please use your browser's BACK button" .
            " to  return to the form and fix your errors.</p>\n";
        }


        if($errors == 0)
        {

            $title = stripslashes($_POST['title']);
            $desc = stripslashes($_POST['desc']);
            $req = stripslashes($_POST['req']);
            $employer = stripslashes($_POST['employer']);
            $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
            $fax = stripslashes($_POST['fax']);
            $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
            $address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
            $insertJob = "INSERT INTO tbljobs (jobTitle, jobDesc, jobReq, jobEmployer, jobPhone, jobFax, jobEmail, jobAddress) VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$req', '$employer', '$phone', '$fax', '$email', '$address')";
                $QueryResult = mysql_query($insertJob, $DBConnect); // Run the Query Now woohoo.
                if($QueryResult === FALSE)
                {
                    echo "<p>Unable to save your job. " .
                    " Error code " .
                    mysql_errno($DBConnect) . ": " .
                    mysql_errno($DBConnect) . "</p>\n";

                    //echo $insertJob;


                    $errors++;
                }
else
{
            echo "Job Lead Saved!";}
            mysql_close($DBConnect);
        }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: please provide some code reference for better understanding

Comment: provide your database logic. It will be then much helpful

Comment: first of all, please get rid off mysql_* and use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead as mysql_* is not maintained anymore, second try removing @ just before `mysql_connect and mysql_delect_db` and also replace `db.start.ca` with `localhost`

Comment: why back to localhost? that works fine

Comment: You shouldn't publish your usernames and passwords on the internet. Someone WILL abuse your DB server.

Comment: lol i didn't these are fake thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

Error 1146 means that you tried to access a table that doesn't exist.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html

Make sure your databases structure is the same on your local and server systems.

Answer (score 2):

> Error: 1146 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE)
>
> Message: Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html

Seems like you have not set up your database tables.

Comment: ok well this is gonna sound like a total noob, but I have never before dealt with databases on a website unless it had a control panel like godaddy, joomla and so on have. this one is from start.ca without a control panel they had to email me the database host name, user name and password. Now I don't know how to load the actual database to it. Anybody know how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I'd recommend you pick up any random SQL tutorial that walks you through the `CREATE TABLE ...` syntax.

Comment: oh that wouldn't be an issue, see I have the SQL exported code in the SQL format, including the create database and add drop tables. Where do I put in this logic to create it on the host?

Answer (score 0):

You've changed your connection info from local database server to online, but did you actually move the local database tables over to the online server?

1146 means that table doesn't exists.

Comment: lol no...I don't know how to do that without a control panel. please excuse my ignorance but I swear i've been google-ing this for a week without any luck.

Comment: Do you already have local database created with all tables and data in them?

Comment: yes, through phpmyadmin and I also have the sql file backed-up for the database creation and adding/dropping tables part including content.

Comment: Then setup a MySQL server on your "online" machine and using phpMyAdmin, or any other tool you feel comfortable with, import the "backed-up" file that contains all the creation and population of your tables.

Comment: the thing is that my hosting company doesn't have a control panel they deal with features through e-mail...so I'd have to do it through code.